# Remounting is not supported at present. You have to umount volume and then mount it once again

Tags: filesystems, mount, readonly, read-write

I was not able to chmod a file in my /dev/sda3 on my Ubuntu12.04 system. This is what I get when I try to see its information:

```
 $ mount | grep 'media'
    /dev/sda2 on /media/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
    /dev/sda6 on /media/sda6 type ext4 (rw)
    /dev/sda3 on /media/sda3 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

When I try to change the mode of /media/sda3 to rw, I get error:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/sda3 
Remounting is not supported at present. You have to umount volume and then mount it once again.
```

So, I unmount /media/sda3

```
$ sudo umount /media/sda3
```

Then when I try to mount it again, I get the same error:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/sda3 
Remounting is not supported at present. You have to umount volume and then mount it once again.
```

I guess, I do not know the right commands. I have done a couple of trial-n-error from google search, but no luck so far. And I am afraid to do a blunder. Any help on how to mount the filesystem with read-write permissions will be great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `-o remount`. That's only useful for remounting, that is, unmounting and mounting again in one operation which isn't supported in your case. Therefore, you need to unmount just like you did and then run:

```
sudo mount -o rw /media/sda3
```

Comment: Hi again. After applying your command, the problem appeared to be solved. However, I am facing a slightly different problem after rebooting my computer.

Comment: `$ cp Makefile ~/
$ gedit ~/Makefile &
[1] 3906
$ touch swas.txt
touch: cannot touch 'swas.txt': Read-only file system
$ cp Makefile Makefile.orig
cp: cannot create regular file 'Makefile.orig': Read-only file system`

Comment: `mount | grep 'media'` shows that `media/sda3` has 'ro' permissions. I can copy files to my home drive, but cannot make changes in the same drive. How to resolve this? Any clue?

Comment: @Swagatika please post a new question explaining exactly what you are trying to do and what happens.